# McNemar exact DP test not running in R

Tags: r, mcnemar-test, exact-test

I am unable to run the provided example (copy/pasted from [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/exact2x2/man/mcnemarExactDP.html)):

```
# For test on contingency table of the pairs
# From Bentur, et al (2009) Pediatric Pulmonology 44:845-850.
# see also Table II of Fagerland, Lydersen and Laake 
# (2013, Stat in Med, 33: 2850-2875)
# 
#                 After SCT
#                 AHR       No AHR
#              ----------------- 
# Before SCT  |    
#         AHR |    1         1 
#      No AHR |    7        12
#              -----------------

ahr<-matrix(c(1,7,1,12),2,2,
            dimnames=list(paste("Before SCT,",c("AHR","No AHR")),
                          paste("After SCT,",c("AHR","No AHR"))))
mcnemarExactDP(n=sum(ahr),m=ahr[1,2]+ahr[2,1], x=ahr[1,2])
# compare to mcnemar.exact
# same p-value, but mcnemar.exact gives conf int on odds ratio 
mcnemar.exact(ahr)
```

Here's what I get in my output when I run that code:

```
> ahr<-matrix(c(1,7,1,12),2,2,
+             dimnames=list(paste("Before SCT,",c("AHR","No AHR")),
+                           paste("After SCT,",c("AHR","No AHR"))))
> mcnemarExactDP(n=sum(ahr),m=ahr[1,2]+ahr[2,1], x=ahr[1,2])
Error in mcnemarExactDP(n = sum(ahr), m = ahr[1, 2] + ahr[2, 1], x = ahr[1,  : 
  could not find function "mcnemarExactDP"
> # compare to mcnemar.exact
> # same p-value, but mcnemar.exact gives conf int on odds ratio 
> mcnemar.exact(ahr)

    Exact McNemar test (with central confidence intervals)

data:  ahr
b = 1, c = 7, p-value = 0.07031
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.003169739 1.111975554
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
 0.1428571
```

Note it cannot find the function "mcnemarExactDP", which is the function I want.

I checked the vignette for exact2x2, which is the package that contains mcnemarExactDP, and it indicates it should be available in package version 1.6.5. I checked my version of exact2x2:

```
> packageVersion("exact2x2")
[1] ‘1.6.5’
```

Can anyone else get this to run? Why can't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `library` call to load the package before you can use it.

```r
library(exact2x2)
#> Loading required package: exactci
#> Loading required package: ssanv
#> Loading required package: testthat
ahr<-matrix(c(1,7,1,12),2,2,
            dimnames=list(paste("Before SCT,",c("AHR","No AHR")),
                          paste("After SCT,",c("AHR","No AHR"))))
mcnemarExactDP(n=sum(ahr),m=ahr[1,2]+ahr[2,1], x=ahr[1,2])
#> 
#>  Exact McNemar Test (with central confidence intervals)
#> 
#> data:  n=sum(ahr) m=ahr[1, 2] + ahr[2, 1] x=ahr[1, 2]
#> n = 21, m = 8, x = 1, p-value = 0.07031
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in proportions is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -0.54549962  0.02044939
#> sample estimates:
#>         x/n     (m-x)/n  difference 
#>  0.04761905  0.33333333 -0.28571429
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hello David, thank you, I did this, but was still not able to run the example.

Comment: The same error occurred.

Comment: Ah - I closed R, re-opened, and it ran. Thank you.